# How to insert whole table into without syntax error included?

Tags: python, sqlite, insert

I'm having a problem with syntax error :

```
    self.db_conn.execute(queryStr,rowData)
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
```

What i am trying to do is to send what i edited in QTableWidget back to SqlLite. ANd there is a problem with syntax that i cannot understand. The names of columns in xlsx and database and everywhere are the same.I am new to python and i am not able to fix the problem :( Please if you know how to fix this just help me out :( Thank you for every answer!

Piece of Code where i am having a problem is below:

```
import sys
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QApplication
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import os.path




class MainWindow(QDialog):

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "zestawienie.db")

    db_conn = sqlite3.connect('zestawienie.db')
    Cursor = db_conn.cursor()


        
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("tabletutorial.ui",self)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(0, 50)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(1, 350)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnWidth(2, 100)
        # self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["Harmonogram", "Uwagi", "DXF", "Nazwa", "Kolumna1"])
        self.testowy.clicked.connect(self.loaddata)
        self.aktualizacja.clicked.connect(self.Aktualizuj)
        self.baza.clicked.connect(self.CreateDB)

        
        
        



    def CreateDB(self):
        

        Zestawienie_test = pd.read_excel(
            'Zestawienie.xlsx', 
            sheet_name='BOM',
            header=0)

        db_conn = sqlite3.connect("zestawienie.db")

        c = db_conn.cursor()

        c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Zestawienie (
        "Harmonogram"   TEXT,
        "Uwagi" TEXT,
        "DXF"   TEXT,
        "Nazwa" TEXT,
        "Kolumna1"  TEXT)
        ''')



        Zestawienie_test.to_sql('Zestawienie', db_conn, if_exists='append', index=False)
        



    def Aktualizuj(self):

        db_conn = sqlite3.connect("zestawienie.db")

        c = db_conn.cursor()
        rowCount =self.tableWidget.rowCount()
        columnCount = self.tableWidget.columnCount()
        for row in range(rowCount):
            rowData = []
            for column in range(columnCount):
                widgetItem = self.tableWidget.item(row,column)
                if(widgetItem and widgetItem.text):
                    rowData.append(widgetItem.text())
                else:
                    rowData.append('NULL')

            print(rowData)
            self.insertRowInDB(rowData)

    def insertRowInDB(self,rowData):
        queryStr = '''INSERT INTO Zestawienie (Harmonogram, Uwagi, DXF, Nazwa, Kolumna1) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)'''
        self.db_conn.execute(queryStr,rowData)
        self.db_conn.commit()
        


    def loaddata(self):
        db_conn = sqlite3.connect('zestawienie.db')
        c = db_conn.cursor()
        sqlstr = 'SELECT * FROM Zestawienie LIMIT 10'

        tablerow=0
        results = c.execute(sqlstr)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(10)
        for row in results:
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[0]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[1]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[2]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[3]))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(tablerow, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(row[4])) 
            tablerow+=1

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = MainWindow()
widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.setFixedHeight(850)
widget.setFixedWidth(1120)
widget.show()
try:
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
except:
    print("Exiting")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sqlite Python driver uses `?` as placeholders, not `%s`:

```py
queryStr = '''INSERT INTO Zestawienie (Harmonogram, Uwagi, DXF, Nazwa, Kolumna1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'''
```